# What to do with a Sizzler?

Tags: equipment, cast-iron, pan

We were gifted a Sizzler yesterday - a sort of elongated shallow cast-iron pan on a wood base for serving and keeping warm at the table. I know these are supposed to be for helping things caramelise, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to serve in it and how to make use of it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, and I should add - I've already begun to season it in the oven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My version of this ( [http://www.amazon.com/Lodge-Logic-Pre-Seasoned-Fajita-Set/dp/B00008GKDP/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008GKDP) ) actually came with a set of instructions. It's not meant to be used for cooking, only for serving. Place the pan in a hot oven for about 30 mins to heat it up (while you're cooking), then put your fajitas on it to bring to the table. The cast iron will retain heat for a long time and keep anything you serve on it sizzling hot.

A cast iron pan would be a great way to cook fajitas, but the shallow sides and strange shape of the "sizzler" pan make it impractical to really cook on. The same instruction book also recommends using another cast iron pan (two, actually) to cook the fajitas.

If you want to use it for something other than fajitas, it would work just fine as a small griddle. You could probably cook pancakes, a strip steak, or chicken breast on it, but nothing that requires any stirring.

Answer (score 3):

My immediate thought is to use it to serve fajitas. They do it in restaurants; why not in your home?

(Just in case, I'm suggesting it for *serving* the meat or veggies, not for grilling them.)

Answer (score 2):

Use it to make pittsburgh style steak.  I absolutely love doing that. Get or cut your own thick 1.5"< steaks. Put the pan in the oven and get it as hot as possible. (be sure to leave the wood place out of the oven :-) )   Turn on the broiler and toss on the steak after coating with the seasoning.   Turn once.  Check the temp to make sure the inside is done to your liking.  I serve it with blue cheese crumbles that melt into the best steak sauce ever.

Other options include fajita steak or chicken with peppers and onions.

Essentially the possibilities are endless.  Just be careful as they will burn you if not handled properly.

Comment: The key for the Pittsburg steak is as you mentioned the caramelization.  The seasoning includes a little sugar to help that along.

Answer (score 0):

If it's large enough to contain a serving or two without spilling while you carefully mix it, you could make a sort of a dolsot bibimbap, which is usually served in a hot cast iron bowl. Heat the pan, then add a layer of cooked rice, then some cooked vegetables and/or meat, crack an egg on top, and stir gently. You'll get a nice crust of rice on the bottom that develops as you eat.